# php-cgi.exe processes cause high cpu usage in IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis-7.5, fastcgi, windows-server, high-load

I have a Windows Server that has random spikes of high CPU usage and upon looking at ProcessExplorer and Windows Task Manager, it seems that there are a high number of php-cgi.exe processes running concurrently, sometimes up to 6-8 instances, all taking around 10-15% of CPU each. Sometimes they are so bad that they cause the server to be unresponsive.

In the FastCGI settings, I've set **MaxInstances** to 4 so by right, so there shouldn't be more than 4 php-cgi.exe processes that are running simultaneously. Hence I would like some advice or directions on how to limit the number of instances to 4..

Additional notes: I've also set **instanceMaxRequests** to 10000 and also **PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS** to 10000 as well.